# Android N Quick Settings Tiles API Tile services order

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-7.0-nougat

My app provides almost 20 custom tiles.
They are displayed into the Quick Settings Editing layout following the order they have been declared in the manifest, which in my case it is by service tile label.
This is resulting into a non alphabetical order when the app has various localization, and the tile label first char might change.
Am I missing something or is there any way to have them alphabetically ordered in various localizations?
I hope I have explained myself.
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that Google was expecting apps to provide zero or one tiles, not almost 20, and so ordering was not high on their list of concerns. If anything, I would argue that they should be sorted within the notification shade editor across all tile providers, not just within one such provider.

Comment: Thank you. I give the user the option to enable or disable any tile to not clutter their quick settings editing layout, by enabling/disabling each component. What do you mean with "they should be sorted within the notification shade editor across all tile providers, not just within one such provider."?

Comment: If I install 10 apps, each of which provide 1+ tiles, I as the user would expect the notification shade editor to show me all the possible tiles from all 10 of those apps... but sorted across all of the apps.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. I believe that when more than one app is providing custom tiles, the frameworks will order them by app name->tile label. Thank you

Comment: Well, that cannot be correct, as otherwise you would not be experiencing the problem that you are. :-) Your proposed approach would be my second choice. If your symptoms are accurate, you are seeing things ordered by app name > position in manifest, and I agree that this makes no sense. OTOH, I do not think that you can control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ordering is controlled by the system. Currently that simply matches the order returned by [queryIntentServices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentServices(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

Comment: Thank you. Since is a package manager call, would a feature request make sense?

Comment: Sure. I think phrasing it as sorting specifically for quick tiles would be more appropriate as sorting by label would be rather expensive to do every time